# C - Register Char Different Size on Windows and Mac

Tags: c, size

I have a `C` program I need to run on both Windows and Mac. Since the code is already working on Windows I prefer to change the Mac "version" to function the same as Windows and leave the code on Windows as is. I have been reading into this and I have already discovered that yes data types have different sizes on different machines/compilers and this is nothing new. Additionally I have seen plenty of questions on purpose the `register` keyword and I am not specifically asking about that but it may be relevant to my issue.

My issue is that I have a few variables defined as `register char` that are strings read from a file and the issue becomes that `sizeof()` on the `register char` variables is 4 on Windows and 8 on Mac and other parts of the program do not function correctly because of this. Unfortunately the program is rather complex so I think my best option is to fix this issue rather than rewrite other parts of the program to accommodate the difference in size for the `register char` variables.

So what I am wondering is can I switch the data type from `register char` to something else if I can find something "equivalent" that uses 4 bytes instead of 8, is there some way I can keep it as is and convert from 8 bytes to 4, or is the best option to rework the rest of the program to accept a value that is either 4 or 8 bytes?

It may also be important to mention this code is in `s_copy.c` from `libf2c` which is part of `f2c`:

```
void s_copy(register char *a, register char *b, ftnlen la, ftnlen lb)
#endif
{
    register char *aend, *bend;

    aend = a + la;
    printf("a: -%lu- %d\n",sizeof(a),__LINE__);
    printf("b: -%lu- %d\n",sizeof(b),__LINE__);

    ...
```

When those print statements are executed on Windows the result printed is 4, on Mac it is 8.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] to demonstrate what you're asking? The size of a `char` doesn't change because you add the register keyword, it is still 1. https://godbolt.org/z/xEc5Gcboc It sounds like you are talking about pointers, with the Windows version compiled as 32-bit and the Mac version compiled as 64-bit.

Comment: `sizeof( char )` is mandated to be `1`. Whether `char` is 8 bits, 9 bits or 16 bits in your particular environment doesn't matter; `sizeof( char )` will always be `1`. Adding `register` in front doesn't change that.

Comment: `a` and `b` are not  `register char`; they are `register char *`. You are getting the size of your system's pointers.

Comment: Those variables are pointers as I suspected. Compile both as 64-bit and the sizes will match. Now explain exactly what the problem is that yu believe the difference in pointer size is causing. It shouldn't matter unless your program requires a larger amount of memory than a 32-bit Windows program can access.

Comment: Given `register char *a`, `sizeof(a)` returns the size of a **pointer** to `char`, not the size of a `char` itself.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre] that demonstrates “other parts of the program do not function correctly because of this.”

Comment: Note: `%lu` is for `long unsigned int`. You should be using `%zu` for `size_t`.

Comment: This difference should generally not cause the program to "not function correctly". You could have a bug that has not been exhibiting symptoms but is with the change.

Comment: _Side note:_ You can remove `register` from the declarations. It was only useful before C compilers did optimization (to force certain variables to live in registers). The optimizer will make better choices about when variables will be put in registers. At best using `register` is harmless if the compiler treats it merely as a hint. At worst it may override the compiler's choices and may produce suboptimal code

Comment: Note also that type `register char *` describes a plain pointer to a `register`-qualified `char`, which is probably not what you meant (and if it *is* what you meant then you need to stop using `register` **right now**).  If, on the other hand, you meant a `register`-qualified pointer to a plain `char`, then that would be `char * register`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Nice catch.  A pointer to a register-qualified type is really quite a mind-bender, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` and `b` are pointers. You are getting the size of pointers. (Well, different type of pointers can have different sizes, but not on systems running Windows and MacOS.)

Your Mac environment is using 64-bit pointers.

Your Windows environment is using 32-bit pointers. This means you are compiling for the x86. If you were to compile the program for the x86-64, you would be using 64-bit pointers there too.

But is the difference in the size of the pointers really the issue? I think the problem is simply that you are using `sizeof(a)` when you should be using `sizeof(*a)`. But since `*a` is a `char`, that's guaranteed to be `1`.

Comment: If you've got a large codebase that's been working for a while in a pure 32-bit environment, there are some portability bugs that tend to crop up when you move to x86_64.  (At least, that's been my experience.)

Comment: The good news is that the "portability bugs that tend to crop up" are all things that a good compiler will warn you about — and on the Mc, the OP is likely to be using either gcc or clang, which both qualify in my book.  So compiling with -Wall, then fixing the warnings, might fix the "other parts of the program do not function correctly".  (Unless there are existing ill-advised casts which silence the warnings, or there are too many warnings to fix.)

Comment: I am using the default Apple clang compiler that is included with Xcode as I am trying to build this into an ios app. Unfortunately I think I am realizing ios apps now have to be 64 bit and so it won't be possible to have only the C code portion compiled as 32 bit.